# Login Error - MyMonero wallet

Tags: mymonero, wallet, issue

I am receiving this error message with ONE of my wallets in the myMonero app:

```
An unexpected application error occurred.

Please let us know of the following error message as it could be a bug:

 <p><span style='font-size: 11px;'>TypeError: Cannot read property 'view' of undefined</span></p>TypeError: Cannot read property 'view' of undefined
    at WalletDetailsView._configureUIWithWallet__accountInfo (C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Wallets\Views\WalletDetailsView.web.js:677:41)
    at WalletDetailsView.setup (C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Wallets\Views\WalletDetailsView.web.js:42:10)
    at new WalletDetailsView (C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Wallets\Views\WalletDetailsView.web.js:29:10)
    at WalletsListView.pushRecordDetailsView (C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Lists\Views\ListView.web.js:232:20)
    at WalletsListView.cellWasTapped (C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Lists\Views\ListView.web.js:251:12)
    at WalletsListCellView.cell_tapped_fn (C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Lists\Views\ListView.web.js:186:15)
    at C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Lists\Views\ListCellView.web.js:96:14
    at WalletsListCellView.overridable_cellTapped (C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Lists\Views\ListCellView.web.js:103:5)
    at WalletsListCellView.__cellTapped (C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Lists\Views\ListCellView.web.js:94:10)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\MyMonero\resources\app.asar\local_modules\Lists\Views\ListCellView.web.js:27:14)Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) MyMonero/1.3.3 Chrome/83.0.4103.122 Electron/9.4.4 Safari/537.36
```

I am tried restarting my PC, reinstalling the app (while retaining files), checking for updates to no avail.

MyMonero support isn't around until Monday, so I am hoping someone here can potentially assist.

The other wallet I have is working fine, so I am not sure what has happened with this wallet.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating that there is an issue with the JavaScript code used by the app, specifically in the **WalletDetailsView**
component. The error suggests that the view property is being accessed on an undefined object, which means that the code is trying to access a view that does not exist or has not been properly initialized.

Try closing the app and then opening it again to see if the problem persists.

Make sure that you are running the latest version of the app.

Clear cache of the app